# GCM push notifications do no arrive in sleep mode on FlymeOS based devices

Tags: android, push-notification

In our app we are using Batch push notification service which is based on GCM.

In recent weeks we have encountered an issue that in some devices the push notification we send do not arrive when the device is on sleep mode. In many cases we had to wake the device and send an additional push and only then it would arrive.

After much investigation we found this suspicious log:
W/GCM-DMM: Force release of GOOGLE_C2DM lock

This log appears whenever a push notification fails to arrive.

It seems this occurs in FlymeOS based devices (Meizu, Xiaomi..). Other devices receive the pushes great. We are always sending them with HIGH priority.

We would appreciate any advice you can give us or any Information regarding why this c2dm lock is being released and how to prevent it.

Thanks in advance,
Mor

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem?

Comment: Not really, we pretty much gave up on FlymeOS and the like. Worth investigating some Chinese Push Notification services and see how they make it work